# Using Angularfire to remove todo items from two templates in order be placed in another and updating Firebase DB

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angular-filters

This question might involve using Angular filters or something else I haven't thought of. I am having trouble deleting my todo items from one template and keeping them in another when a date has expired on my todo list. I am using angularfire for the database.

What I have now is a todo list that asks for something 'todo' and a date of completion. If the user hasn't completed the todo in 7 days, the todo gets removed and is supposed to be placed in the expiry table. A todo that has expired is put on the 'expired todo' table, except the todo is not deleted from the 'current' todo list.

**Question:** How would I remove the todo from the 'current todo' list while keeping it on the 'expired todo' list? Another issue I have is getting the Firebase DB to update "expired" from "false" to "true". I know it's doing it in the browser, because I put a $watch on it, but it's not pushing over to the DB.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

(I think one part is the way that I did the filter, but there is something else I am missing for sure.)

Inside Angular Controller:

```
  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.$add({
      text: $scope.newTodo,
      date: $scope.newDate,
      done: false,
      expired: false
    });
    $scope.newTodo = '';
    $scope.newDate = '';
  };   

$scope.removeTodo = function(todo) {
    $scope.todos.$remove(todo);
  };

$scope.todoChange = function(todo) {
    if(todo.done && $scope.show === 'Complete'){
       return true;
    } else if(!todo.done && $scope.show === 'Current'){
      return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
  };

$scope.todoExpired = function(todo) { 
  var today = new Date();
  var fDate = new Date(todo.date);
  fDate.setDate(fDate.getDate() + 7);

    if (today > fDate) {
      return true;
        } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Here is the partial HTML for the tables:

Current page:

```
<tr class='results' ng-repeat='(id, todo) in todos | filter:todoChange'>
    <td><span>{{$index + 1}}</scan></td>
    <td><span>{{todo.text}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{todo.date}}</span></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='todo.done' ng-change='todos.$save(todo)'></td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='removeTodo(todo)'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Expire page:

```
<tr class='results' ng-repeat='todo in todos | filter:todoExpired'>
    <td><span>{{$index + 1}}</scan></td>
    <td><span>{{todo.text}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{todo.date}}</span></td>
    <td>Expired</td>
    <td><button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='removeTodo(todo)'>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE:**

Figured out I had to put `ng-hide='todoExpired(todo)'` in the table. This made all expired todos hidden on the current page and only viewed on the expired page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out through the `$watch()` and adding `ng-hide='todoExpired(todo)'` to the 'current' table.

The `watch()` code is as follows:

```
$scope.todos.$watch(function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if(oldValue == newValue) {return;}
   _.each($scope.todos, function(element, item, index) {
    if ($scope.todoExpired(element)) { 
     element.expired = true;
     $scope.todos.$save(element);
   } 
  })
});
```

I don't know how efficient this answer is, but it does the trick.

Comment: What does todoExpered(todo) check? It should be completely unnecessary to have a $watch event here as the ng-hide will automatically call todoExpired() any time the data changes.

Comment: Yes, the ng-hide does the trick, but using ng-hide does not update to 'true' in the Firebase db for the property 'expired'. If you know of a way that is far easier to update the property in the db, by all means I would like to know. I am not going to pretend, I have used Firebase for only two weeks, and learnt javascript about a month ago, and angular three weeks ago. So, I am an amateur at best.